# Minimum Modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

i would like to clarify for the theorem of minimum modulus, if $f(z) = 0$ for some $z$ in the region of analyticity, then our minimum modulus will occur at that point $z$ where $f(z) = 0$? Because the theorem always claim that $f(z)$ is non vanishing throughout, so i got a bit confused to what will happen if $f(z)  =0$

Comment: Nothing will happen if $f(z) =0$, instead you will need some criteria other than the minimum modulus principle to obtain useful information about $f$.

Comment: Well i was doing a question and it explicitly asked me to find the minimum modulus of $z^{2}-z$ in the closed ball $|z| \leq 1$. So i think there is a minimum modulus even though $f(z) = 0$ at $z=0,1$

Comment: I find this question very funny. For one, it's specified the function you are working with, while the minimum modulus principle is useful in telling you when functions are constant. Next, minimum modulus isn't applicable for functions with zeros in the given domain, while here there is a zero. Can you take a photo of the textbook/page and paste it, because I'm still a little surprised that one would ask such a simple question while attempting to invoke the minimum modulus principle. But I apologize if that's actually the question, I'm just taken aback.

Comment: Here attached is the picture, i will take it down once you have read it as i do not wish to disclose my professor's identity

Comment: Please take it down, I have read it. Thank you for putting it up, so $+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as I had thought. So the minimum modulus principle does *not apply* to $z^2 - z$. Instead, the question is elementary ,and to find  the minimum moduli you simply have to find the roots of $z^2 - z$ over the given domain, which occur when $z =0, z=1$. This is simple arithmetic, not requiring the min modulus principle.

What the *maximum* modulus principle will tell you (and it's applicable) is that since $z^2 - z$ is not constant, it's modulus must be taking a maximum on the boundary, so the advantage we get from MMT : *it's enough to search on the boundary if you want the maximum, rather than search the whole domain*.

A  search on  the boundary yields that $z=-1$  satisfies $|z^2 - z| =  2$, which is the largest it can be, since $|z^2-z| \leq |z^2| + |z| \leq 1 +  1 \leq 2$, so  the maximum is attained at this point. There's no need to search in the interior because of MMT, so you are done.

Indeed, this is a nice application of Maximum MT , because you can restrict finding maximums of non-constant functions to the boundary of a given domain , rather than search the whole domain. If the boundary is nice, then this makes the search much easier.

Comment: Oh, so we do not invoke minimum modulus principle here?

Comment: That's right. The maximum modulus principle is the one invoked here, since it's the one applicable.

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply.

Comment: You are welcome!